# Shuffle DevExpress GridControl DataSource

Tags: data-binding, gridview, c#-4.0, devexpress

I need to shuffle the GridControl's DataSource. I use this property in a UserControl:

```
private List<Song> _songsDataSource;
public List<Song> SongsDataSource
{
    get { return _songsDataSource; }
    set
    {
        _songsDataSource = value;
        if (!value.IsNull())
        {
            SongsBindingList = new BindingList<Song>(value);
            songsBinding.DataSource = SongsBindingList;
        }
    }
}
```

Then i use a method that i clone, shuffle and append to the SongsDataSource property:

```
    List<Song> newList = HelpClasses.Shuffle((List<Song>) SongsDataSource.Clone());
    SongsDataSource = newList;

public static List<Song> Shuffle(List<Song> source)
        {
            for (int i = source.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                int n = rng.Next(i + 1);
                Song tmp = source[n];
                source[n] = source[i - 1];
                source[i - 1] = tmp;
            }
            return source;
        }
```

Strange thing is that it doesn't seem to reflect the changes to the GridControl even i use the GridControl.RefreshDataSource() method after set the SongsDataSource method. If i check the DataSource order, shuffle was happened successfully.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've changed the object originally set as a DataSource, calling `RefreshDataSource()` won't do any good cause you can't refresh something that's no longer there. Your problem is here:

```
List<Song> newList = HelpClasses.Shuffle((List<Song>) SongsDataSource.Clone());
SongsDataSource = newList;   // the reference has changed, the grid doesn't know what to do when RefreshDataSource() is called.
```

You can pass the list as it is, without the need of cloning it. Also surround the `Shuffle()` method call with `gridControl.BeginUpdate()` end `gridControl.EndUpdate()` to prevent any updates to the grid while the elements of the `DataSource` are changing.

Comment: I'm passing on the Shuffle() method the BindingSource.DataSource and still nothing happens, where is a BindingList<Song>. Added the BeginUpdate(), EndUpdate() methods and after called the RefreshDatasource() with no luck still.

Comment: try setting the List<Song> as DataSource without using a BindingList<T>. eg. gridControl.DataSource = SongsDataSource.

Comment: also check if you have sorting on any of the columns, cause that would automatically sort the records in your grid and shuffling would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problems with DevExpress GridControl. I think, that this situation caused by GridView(http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridViewtopic), which creates automaticly for each GridControl. 
This is part of GridControl responsible for visualization of DataSource. 
If you need to change DataSource try:

```
GridView.Columns.Clear();
GridControl.DataSource = You_New_DataSource;
GridView.RefreshData();
GridControl.RefreshDataSource();
```